# Android - Barcode Fragment result not displaying

Tags: java, android, zxing

[SOLVED]
The apps work fine without crash, but it should be update the resultView text from "Hasil Scan" to the scan result, but it doesnt. The problem are the textview (resultView) are not updated after scan. Im using DM77 Zxing barcode scanner.
Here is the code i have done so far.

MainActivity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import sc.smklabor.rpl.labsscanner.sc.smklabor.rpl.labsscanner.fragments.ScanFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.scannav:
                                selectedFragment = ScanFragment.instance();
                                break;
                        }
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                        transaction.commit();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, ScanFragment.instance());
        transaction.commit();

    }
}
```

and here is for the scanner fragment, i only have done one fragment, other fragment just will be about and website
ScanFragment:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

import sc.smklabor.rpl.labsscanner.R;

/**
 * Created by Lenovo on 21/03/2018.
 */

public class ScanFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private IntentIntegrator scanner;
    private Button startScan,btnGoUrl;
    private TextView resultView;
    private String scanResult;

    public static ScanFragment instance() {
        ScanFragment f = new ScanFragment();
        return f;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        scanner = new IntentIntegrator(this.getActivity()).forSupportFragment(this);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int rc,int res, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(rc, res, data);
        if(result!=null) {
            scanResult = result.getContents().toString();
            if (scanResult.contains("--L--:")) {
                String postId = scanResult.split("://")[1];
                btnGoUrl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                resultView.setText("Post ID: " + postId);
            } else if (URLUtil.isHttpUrl(scanResult) || isValidURL(scanResult)) {
                btnGoUrl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                resultView.setText(result.getContents().toString());
            } else {
                btnGoUrl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                resultView.setText(result.getContents().toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inf, ViewGroup con, Bundle b) {
        View view = inf.inflate(R.layout.scanlayout, con, false);
        startScan = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnGoUrl = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnGoUrl);
        scanner = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
        startScan.setOnClickListener(this);
        resultView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        btnGoUrl.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View e) {
                Uri URL = Uri.parse(scanResult);
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,URL);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    public boolean isValidURL(String s) {
        return (s.contains("http://") || s.contains("https://")) && (s.contains(".com") || s.contains(".org") || s.contains(".net") || s.contains(".id") || s.contains(".sch.id") || s.contains(".me"));
    }

    public void onClick(View e) {
        scanner.setPrompt("Arahkan kamera kepada barcode tepat pada kotak.");
        scanner.setOrientationLocked(false);
        scanner.initiateScan();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set and hit a breakpoint on resultView.setText("Post ID: " + postId);

Comment: what do you mean by breakpoint? the code work fine before i transform the layout into fragment. so at the resultView.setText() have no problem.

Comment: The information you give is not a lot to go on "The textview are not updated after scan" Are you getting anything back from onActivityResult

Comment: I dont know, but after the barcode is scanned, the textview should be updated, but it doesnt

Comment: The code is totally clear, and the main case are in ScanFragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the `onActivityResult` is not called in the `ScanFragment`

First you should override the `onActivityResult(int rc,int res, Intent data)`
on the `MainActivity`

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_layout);
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

This code it will help you call the `onActivityResult` on the `ScanFragment`.

Comment: i have tried that, i put that code in my mainactivity, it crash

Comment: @DariusEllertKlaus Can you give me the crash log?